# Gatekeeper Graph

Tags: graph-theory

> From the book [Networks, Crowds, and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch02.pdf). Definitions are on page 45, questions are on page 46.

A node X is a gatekeeper if, for some other two nodes Y and Z, every path from Y to Z passes through X. (It lies on every path between other pairs of nodes)

A node X is a local gatekeeper if there are two neighbors of X, say Y and Z, that are not connected by an edge. (That is, for X to be a local gatekeeper, there should be two nodes Y and Z such that Y and Z each have edges to X, but not to each other.)

If then,

1. Give an example of a graph in which more than half of all nodes are gatekeepers.
2. Give an example of a graph in which there are no gatekeepers but in which every node is a local gatekeeper

[Question 2- Not gatekeeper but every node is a Local Gatekeeper. Whether it is correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjPkG.png)

[Question 1- More than half of all nodes are gatekeepers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vHOp.png)

Comment: Give a definition of gatekeeper. Give a definition of local gatekeeper.

Comment: A node X is a gatekeeper if, for some other two nodes Y and Z, every path from Y to Z passes through X. (It lies on every path between other pairs of nodes).

Comment: A node X is a local gatekeeper if there are two neighbors of X, say Y and Z, that are not connected by an edge. (That is, for X to be a local gatekeeper, there should be two nodes Y and Z such that Y and Z each have edges to X, but not to each other.)

Comment: Could you edit your quesiton so it contains these definitions?

Comment: My answer to question number 2 is added as a reference at the end of the question.

Comment: Your answer to question 2 looks good. For question 1, try 5 nodes connected in a line.

Comment: I have added at the end as reference another image as solution to question 1. Is it correct?

Comment: I've cited the book for you. In the future please do not copy verbatim from any source without citation, that's plagiarism.

Answer (score 2):

One answer to part 1) any line graph on at least 5 vertices and
              part 2) any cycle graph